# How to get Heroku to recognize a yarn.lock or package.json within a subdirectory (not root)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, procfile, yarnpkg

I have a Rails application using React, Webpack, and Yarn for the client side. I have everything relating to the client side within the /client directory. This includes my yarn.lock and package.json files. I have a Procfile that cds into /client and properly runs `yarn run build`. This works locally with no errors. However, when I deploy/push to Heroku, my push is rejected and I get the following error:

```
remote:        cd client && yarn run build:production
remote:        sh: 1: yarn: not found
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        Command failed with status (127): [cd client && yarn run build:production...]
```

What this says to me is that Heroku wasn't able to find a yarn.lock file in the root level. How do I get Heroku to use the `yarn.lock` file within my /client directory?

Or is the cause of this error something else entirely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just been through a similar thing myself. You need to order the buildpacks so that node is first. If a yarn.lock is in your root dir (or yarn is in your "engines" key as in @remydib's answer), then the node buildpack will install yarn and then your packages. If you have a `yarn.lock` in /client, put one in root, and add a `postinstall` script to it that says `cd client && yarn run build`.

In my case (rake assets:precompile calls yarn and fails), for some reason when the buildpacks go ruby -> node, Heroku doesn't wait for node to install before trying to run rake tasks, and we go kablooie.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It works. But I wonder why we have to put NodeJS buildpacks at the first place?

Comment: @hiveer The NodeJS Buildpack is needed to make sure that node and npm/yarn are available.

Answer (score 17):

Make sure to use both ruby and node buildpacks. I got this error when I didn't.

Execute these in your root folder:

```
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
```

Sources: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app

https://github.com/shakacode/react_on_rails/blob/master/docs/additional-reading/heroku-deployment.md

Answer (score 1):

maybe your can try typing in package.json

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "^6.9",
    "yarn": "^0.21"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To use `yarn` to install your application's dependences

   a) `yarn.lock` should be present in root of the repo.

   `yarn install`

   b) `package-lock.json` should be removed

   `git rm package-lock.json`
2. To use `npm`

   a) `yarn.lock` should be removed

Source: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-support#installed-binaries

https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package-lock.json

Answer (score 0):

I'll add an answer for document another possible use-case. I experienced something similar, multiple buildpacks and I had checked everything in all answers:

- `node-js` was declared first in `.buildpacks` file
- a `yarn.lock` was added in the root of the project
- yarn dependency declared under engines on `package.json`

Nevertheless `yarn` was not picking up since I was using an older version of node-js buildpack.

---

**Bumping the version of the buildpack the latest** solve my problem:

```
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs#v118
```

Answer (score 0):

You can keep both package.json and yarn.lock by adding one of these to
.slugignore.

It works like .gitignore - it just defines which files to ignore pushing to Heroku.

[Check more information here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-compiler#ignoring-files-with-slugignore)